# Decreasing of power function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Show that $\frac{3}{4}(x-2)x^{-\frac{5}{2}}-(x+1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}<0$, wherer $x\ge0$.

I tried by taking differentiation but then expression become more complicated. I also tried by checking the behavior these two terms which decrease rapidly.

Comment: An approach woud be to rewrite the inequality $$ \frac{x^{5/2}}{(x+1)^{3/2}}  \stackrel{?}{>}  \frac{3}{4}(x-2)$$ which clearly holds for $0 \leq x\leq 2$; and for $x > 2$, can be squared on both sides to give you something simpler to study: $$ \frac{x^{5}}{(x+1)^{3}(x-2)^2} \stackrel{?}{>} \frac{9}{16}$$

Comment: I misread, so had deleted the comment. But not fast enough.

Comment: Following Clement's comment, it is enough to show that $16(x+2)^5-9(x+3)^3x^2$ on expansion has only positive coefficients.

Comment: @Nemo This is true, $$16(x+2)^5−9(x+3)^3x^2 =7x^5+79x^4+397x^3+1037x^2+1280x+512.$$